# Default value in django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, default

I created a model with these feilds. I want to set the `start_date` and `end_date` to a default date whenever the attendance is registered however, when I migrate I get this error

> django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“26/06/2022” value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.']

the model in model.py

```
class Attendance(models.Model):
    ATTENDANCE = (
        ('absent', 'Absent'),
        ('present', 'Present')
    )
    student_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    course_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    attendanceState = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True,choices=ATTENDANCE)
    start_date = models.DateField(default=2022-2-27)
    week_num = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(default=2022-6-27)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.student_id)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #print(self.start_date.isocalendar()[1])
        if self.week_num == "":
            self.week_num = self.start_date.isocalendar()[1]
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: `default='2022-6-27'`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem still am not able to migrate I get the same error :(

Comment: just on the fly: 2022-2-27 is not YYYY-MM-DD but is YYYY-M-DD so I would put:

(default='2022-02-27')

Comment: @Carlo I did try that too, still getting the same error, Idk where it get '“26/06/2022” from I didn't use it anywhere in the code!!

Comment: @Zoe: llikely because the migration file was already created. You should remove that one, and create a new one.

Comment: @Zoe: two things; a) cancel all the data; should be the case you have a dirty default data in your table that is blocking migration; this is not infrequent whenever updating models.py and creating objects via admin.
b) then, rerun makemigrations and migrate

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how do I do that am afraid to do so then the whole thing crash :'(

Comment: @Carlo I did remove the data from the database and tried to migrate but still same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the migrations before, I think that is the issue,
moreover change the default date value to

```
start_date = models.DateField(default='2022-02-27')
end_date = models.DateField(default='2022-06-27')
```

then makemigrations and migrate, run the server, you will see something like this on the django admin:
[Add Attendance in django admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsZiV.png)